# Multiple CAShapeLayers with .round lineCap are overlapped by each other

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, calayer

I try to combine multiple layers using `.round` `lineCap` and a semicircle path:

```swift
let layer = CAShapeLayer()
layer.lineWidth = 12
layer.lineCap = .round
layer.strokeColor = color.withAlphaComponent(0.32).cgColor
layer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
```

```swift
// angles calculation
let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter,
                        radius: radius,
                        startAngle: startAngle,
                        endAngle: engAngle,
                        clockwise: true)
layer.path = path.cgPath
```

trying to achieve the following:

[image]

but my layers are overlapped by each other. Is it possible to fix it somehow fast or do I need to implement path calculating with rounded corners manually?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `.lineCap = .round` we get a "circle" centered at the endpoint with a radius of 1/2 the line width:

[image]

So, to get the circle-round end to sit at the endpoint, we can adjust the endpoint by `asin(lineWidth * 0.5 / radius)`:

[image]

Assuming we're going in a clockwise direction:

```
let delta: CGFloat = lineCap == .round ? asin(lineWidth * 0.5 / radius) : 0.0

let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                        radius: radius,
                        startAngle: startDegrees.radians + delta,
                        endAngle: endDegrees.radians - delta,
                        clockwise: true)
```

So, if we have a series of degrees forming this image with `.lineEnd = .butt` (the default):

[image]

we can get this by offsetting the start and end angles:

[image]

Here's a complete example class:

```
class ConnectedArcsView: UIView {
    
    public var segmentDegrees: [CGFloat] = [] {
        didSet {
            var n: Int = 0
            if let subs = layer.sublayers {
                n = subs.count
                if n > segmentDegrees.count {
                    // if we already have sublayers,
                    //  remove any extras
                    for _ in 0..<n - segmentDegrees.count {
                        subs.last?.removeFromSuperlayer()
                    }
                }
            }
            // add sublayers if needed
            while n <  segmentDegrees.count {
                let l = CAShapeLayer()
                l.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                layer.addSublayer(l)
                n += 1
            }
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    // segment colors default: [.red, .green, .blue]
    public var segmentColors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue] { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    // line width default: 12
    public var lineWidth: CGFloat = 12 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    // line cap default: .round
    public var lineCap: CAShapeLayerLineCap = .round  { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        guard let subs = layer.sublayers else { return }
        
        let radius = (bounds.size.width - lineWidth) * 0.5
        let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        
        // if lineCap == .round
        //  calculate delta for start and end angles
        let delta: CGFloat = lineCap == .round ? asin(lineWidth * 0.5 / radius) : 0.0
        
        // calculate start angle so the "gap" is centered at the bottom
        let totalDegrees: CGFloat = segmentDegrees.reduce(0.0, +)
        var startDegrees: CGFloat = 90.0 + (360.0 - totalDegrees) * 0.5
        
        for i in 0..<segmentDegrees.count {
            let endDegrees = startDegrees + segmentDegrees[i]
            
            guard let shape = subs[i] as? CAShapeLayer else { continue }
            
            shape.lineWidth = lineWidth
            shape.lineCap = lineCap
            shape.strokeColor = segmentColors[i % segmentColors.count].cgColor
            
            let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                                    radius: radius,
                                    startAngle: startDegrees.radians + delta,
                                    endAngle: endDegrees.radians - delta,
                                    clockwise: true)
            
            shape.path = path.cgPath
            
            startDegrees += segmentDegrees[i]
        }
        
    }

}
```

and an example view controller showing its usage:

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let testView = ConnectedArcsView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        let degrees: [CGFloat] = [
            40, 25, 140, 25, 40
        ]
        
        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemYellow, .systemGreen, .systemYellow, .systemRed
        ] //.map { ($0 as UIColor).withAlphaComponent(0.5) }
        
        testView.segmentDegrees = degrees
        testView.segmentColors = colors
        testView.lineWidth = 12
        
        testView.backgroundColor = .black
        testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(testView)
        
        // add an info label
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "Tap anywhere to toggle between\n\".round\" and \".butt\""
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            testView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            testView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor),
            
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.widthAnchor),
            v.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: testView.centerXAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        testView.lineCap = testView.lineCap == .round ? .butt : .round
    }
    
}
```

When running, tapping anywhere will toggle between `.round` and `.butt`.

---

**Edit** - forgot to include the helper extension:

```
extension CGFloat {
    var degrees: CGFloat {
        return self * CGFloat(180) / .pi
    }
    var radians: CGFloat {
        return self * .pi / 180.0
    }
}
```

---

**Edit 2** - *in response to comment on 11/8/2022...*

This custom `ConnectedArcsView` class is ***not yet finished***. For example, it's easy to "exceed the bounds" as it were.

Suppose we use `[120, 20, 120]` for our degrees, and we have a view width which gives us a circumference of `360-points` for our circle (approx 115 points wide).

With `.lineCap = .butt`, the 20-degree arc-segment will be 20-points long. Because it's the "top" arc, it will start at 260-degrees and end at 280-degrees.

With `.lineCap = .round`, one-half the `.lineWidth` will be added onto each end of that arc-segment. Suppose the `.lineWidth` is `8`... the arc-segment will now be 28-points long, which is no longer 20-degrees of the circle.

So, we adjust the endpoints. The **actual** arc-segment is now 12-points long, the rounded ends are 4-points each bringing the full length of the *rounded* segment to 20-points. So, still 20-degrees, and the calculated start/end degrees are 264 and 276.

Change the `.lineWidth` to `12`, and we get arc-segment length: 8 + 6 on each end = 20-points, or 20-degrees, with calculated start/end degrees of 266 and 274.

So --- what happens if we set `.lineWidth = 24`?

Our 20-degree / 20-point arc-segment must have **12-points** on each end! So the **actual** arc-segment is now ***MINUS 4-points***!

And, the calculated start/end degrees are 272 and 268 -- in other words, it will go *almost all the way around the circle*.

[image]

To put this class into a production environment, one would likely modify it to account for that, and probably throw an exception (which would need to be handled).

In addition, note that if we use these values for our degree-segments:

```
let degrees: [CGFloat] = [
    120, 60, 100, 70, 90
]
```

we end up with a total of **440-degrees** and the segments will overlap - which is almost certainly not desired.

So, the values would need to be "normalized," along with (probably) a "gap" value for the bottom.

Comment: clicked a bounty for the awesome answer.  You know, I believe the formula `asin(lineWidth * 0.5 / radius)` is not exactly correct (try it with a very large line thickness, say a quarter the radius of the circle, and you'll do a "Doh!" !)  Cheers!

Comment: @Fattie - well, yes and no. `asin(lineWidth * 0.5 / radius)` ***is*** correct... but the class needs some additional work before it should be considered "production ready." See the **Edit 2** at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: cheers @DonMag .. interesting; I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing. stand by for a diagram!  :)

Comment: consider this. look at the very first small image in the answer. imagine that huge.  imagine the (two) radial lines (from the center of the overall circle), which, touch ie are tangent to the yellow circle.  (by yellow circle, I simply mean the circular edge of the yellow coin)  consider the left one. the point where it meets the yellow circle actually *is not* the point where the blue line, meets the yellow circle - it's lower than that!  Uhh .. I think.

Comment: @Fattie - ah... do you mean this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/500UE.png

Comment: yes, the meeting point of "coins inside a channel" is no on the radius of the channel, it's a bit inside that.  So if you do want them to JUST kiss, the formula mentioned is not correct.  (I THINK!  :) :) )   Pls note that we may be discussing slightly different issues; a lot of ground has been covered ...  :O

Comment: @Fattie - if we want the **tangent points** to be on the radius, we no longer have the center-line of the arcs on the radius. Consider this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a1B2.png -- two "coins" with their centers on the blue circles, and their tangent points on the green circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249453/discussion-between-donmag-and-fattie).